# Win7 Graphic distortion after opening game

Tags: windows-7, mac, boot-camp, osx-mountain-lion, graphics

I installed Windows 7 on MBP 13" 2012 using bootcamp. I have downloaded all drivers etc, system is updated. When I open EvE Online game client, the application works normally, although the graphics in Windows interface become distorted and only return to normal with system restart. Same game runs fine in OSX, while using more resources than windows client. Any ideas as to how I can fix this ?

```
CPU TYPE:
Intel® Core™ i7-3520M CPU @ 2.90GHz
CPU SPEED:
2.92 GHz
SYSTEM MEMORY:
8 GB
VIDEO CARD MODEL:
Intel HD Graphics 4000
VIDEO CARD MEMORY:
580 MB
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check for a hardware problem in either your monitor or graphic card.

Comment: It cant be hardware problem as the application works fine and the problem is fixed with restart.

Comment: There is some hardware initialization done at restart you realize.

Comment: +1 - Games make a graphics card work harder and use more of the hardware. 3d rendering for example, won't get much of a workout on a desktop. The most common fault I come across (the system I maintain has over 100 graphic engines) is duff graphics memory that is only called as the workload increases and so doesn't show errors outside of graphic intensive apps.

Comment: There is no such problem when running same game on OSX. Also in windows it consumes less resources (as the native client is for windows). Still supposing this is the problem, what steps can I take to fix it/ verify it?